# Regex negative lookahead in c#

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, regex-negation

I need to match `["this"` but not `:["this"`

I have this code:

```
        Match match = Regex.Match(result, @"\[""(.*?)""",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        while (match.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim());
        }
```

I have tried the pattern `@"(?!:)\[""(.*?)"""`,  but it still match `:["this"`. Whats the pattern I need to achieve this?

Comment: What? I dont understand what you said. What I need is to match ["this" when it doesn't have a : in the beginning, If I remove the colon out of @"(?!:)\[""(.*?)""" it doesn't match anything even when it doesn't start with :

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking ahead (rightwards in the string) when you want to be looking behind (leftwards in the string).

Try `@"(?<!:)\[""(.*?)"""` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I used RegexBuddy (I love that app) set to .NET and got the following expression:

```
@"(?<!:)\[""(.*?)"""
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a negative lookahead when you should be doing a negative *lookbehind*. Try this instead:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(result, @"(?<!:)\[""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```