# C# - Negative Lookahead doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Working in C# .Net 4.5

I need an expression that will look through a string and fail the match if the string has two or more capital characters anywhere in the string.

What I think should be the correct pattern is this:

```
(?![A-Z]{2,})\w
```

Note: tried both `?!` and `?<!`

I got the opposite to work, search a string and return true if there are 2 or more cap's in a row and that pattern is as follows:

```
(?=[A-Z]{2,})\w
```

But I have to have this working off of the negative lookahead pattern.

From all the posts I've read this should be the correct way to do it, but it's not working for me.

I've read through questions such as :

[C# regexp negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407474/c-sharp-regexp-negative-lookahead)
or
[Regex negative lookahead in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081504/regex-negative-lookahead-in-c-sharp)

etc...

I don't want to list them all. But they all say more or less the same thing, just use the negative lookahead (?!)

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong for this not to work?

Edit:

added some examples:

1. Hello   - Should pass
2. HEllo   - Should fail
3. heLLo   - Should fail
4. HELLO   - should fail

Advanced version:

1. Hello World    - should pass
2. Hello WOrld    - should fail
3. hello wORld    - should fail
4. hello WORLD    - should fail

Comment: Anywhere  in the *word*? Like `\b(?!\w*\p{Lu}\w*\p{Lu})\w+\b`?

Comment: could you give us some examples with expected and actual outcome?

Comment: Well anywhere in the sentence really, but starting with just 1 word for now and will go from there. But yes anywhere in the word.

Comment: @user1255276 this regex matches word if it contains at least two capital letter `^(.*?[A-Z]){2,}.*$`

Comment: If you want fail a string match tht has at least two capital letters, use `(?s)^(?!\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}).*$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?!.*\b\w*\p{Lu}\w*\p{Lu}).*$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F!.*%5Cb%5Cw*%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cw*%5Cp%7BLu%7D).*%5Cr%3F%24&i=Hello%20World%0D%0AHello%0D%0A%0D%0AHEllo%0D%0AheLLo%0D%0AHELLO%0D%0AHello%20WOrld%0D%0Ahello%20wORld%0D%0Ahello%20WORLD&o=m)

It will match empty string, too, but you can use `+` quantifier instead of `*` to require at least 1 character.

To match a newline with this pattern, you will need to use `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier.

The negative lookahead `(?!.*\b\w*\p{Lu}\w*\p{Lu})` anchored at the start of the string will fail the match once a word is found that starts with zero or more word characters, followed by a captital letter, again followed by zero or more word characters and then again an uppercase letter. You can shorten this with a limiting quantifier: `^(?!.*\b(?:\w*\p{Lu}){2}).*$`.

Comment: Matches `The Hello-World Corporation` but not `The HelloWorld Corporation`

Answer (score 1):

You only need to FAIL a match if you are trying to match something.

What you are trying to match is the failure.

if `[A-Z].*?[A-Z]` matches the string contains 2 cap letters.

If not two in a row, its this (multi-line) -> `^[^A-Z\r\n]*(?:[A-Z](?![A-Z])[^A-Z\r\n]*)*$`

To match a non-empty string, just add a simple assertion.

`^(?!$)[^A-Z\r\n]*(?:[A-Z](?![A-Z])[^A-Z\r\n]*)*$`

For Unicode properties, use the `\p{Lu}` form

`^[^\p{Lu}\r\n]*(?:\p{Lu}(?!\p{Lu})[^\p{Lu}\r\n]*)*$`

---

Input:

```
1.Hello - Should pass
2.HEllo - Should fail
3.heLLo - Should fail
4.HELLO - should fail

Advanced version:
1.Hello World - should pass
2.Hello WOrld - should fail
3.hello wORld - should fail
4.hello WORLD - should fail
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   ^(?!.*\b\w*\p{Lu}\w*\p{Lu}).*$
Options:  < ICU - m >
Completed iterations:   80  /  80     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    8.28 s,   8279.28 ms,   8279281 µs


Regex2:   ^[^\p{Lu}\r\n]*(?:\p{Lu}(?!\p{Lu})[^\p{Lu}\r\n]*)*$
Options:  < ICU - m >
Completed iterations:   80  /  80     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    3.88 s,   3875.04 ms,   3875039 µs
```

Comment: can't do it this way, its a parse file with regex patterns in the file, and all patterns in the file need to be in a pass state.

Comment: Thanks sln. Appreciate your help.